# Javascript, convert an array to a string like so

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I want to convert an array to a sting so that visually it is just the same but with quote marks around it.

For example:

```
array= [1,2,3,[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

goes to =>  "[1,2,3,[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]"
```

I tried `String(array)` but this just punches through all the brackets to give me:

```
"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"
```

Anyone got any ideas on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

```
JSON.stringify(array);
```

> The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is specified, or optionally including only the specified properties if a replacer array is specified.

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.stringify`

```js
array= [1,2,3,[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.stringify`

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify([1,2,3,[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
array = array.join(",");
array = array.split(",");
array = array.join("");
```

This should take care of the sub-arrays.